# Dynamics Ax: how to copy a value from a field to another?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++

i've a form with 2 text box (RealEdit): one field is bounded to a table field.. another one is simply a text box not bounded. 
How to copy the value from the first to the second text box ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set autodeclare propoertie of the second field to true.
then in your code do

```
mySecondField.value(myTable.firstField)
```

where myTable.firstField is the field bound to the first control (not the first control him self)